# Windows Phone Emulator requires missing Hyper-V

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm beginner in Windows Phone 8, I installed Windows Phone 8 SDK and when I started the emulator I had this error message

> "The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V. Your PC is missing the
>   following pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V: Windows 8
>   Professional (64-bit)"

I have Windows 8 Professional (64-bit) OS on my lap-top, and I looked up in "Turn some windows features on/off" and I saw that Hyper-V is missing, I went into the BIOS but without results.

Processor type Intel Core i7-3630, SLAT supporting.

Comment: What kind of processor does your pc have?

Comment: Intel Core i7-3630, and now I checked if my processor support SLAT, it supports, but Hypervisor isn't present.

Comment: can you run `systeminfo` from the command prompt. It should have a section at the bottom telling you if you have the pre-requisites to run Hyper-V. You can also run `msinfo32` from the start and look for something like: http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-57-25-metablogapi/2480.011813_5F00_0935_5F00_HyperVonCli2.png

Comment: System type: x64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

Comment: @AlastairPitts I run systeminfo and I get all YES for Hyper-V requirements.

Comment: @AlastairPitts all four reqirements are YES

Comment: Katerina: Very strange :/ Try the 2nd suggested solution in this thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprovirt/thread/a2000a11-47be-4748-9d21-517b29f1bc72/ (the one about using powershell)

Comment: I think I'm going to reinstall my VS 2012 and WP 8 SDK. Thank you anyway

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have SLAT Support, you are on Windows 8 Professional (64-bit), and you have virtualization enabled in BIOS....

How to Enable Hyper-V:

1. Remove all Instances of VMware, VirtualBox, or any other Virtualizing Sofware.
2. Go to Control Panel (From Desktop View Right click bottom left corner)
3. Select Programs
4. Select "Turn Windows Features on and off"
5. Make sure the Hyper-V box is checked and hit OK.

If all these things are done correctly, Hyper-V should be enabled and working.

Comment: My pc have all hardware Requirement but i cant run emulator , Im using Windows 8.1 Single Language, i think because of this I can't add Hyper-V from Windows Features. In my windows features there is no option like Hyper-V . Is there any alternative to do this.