# Windows Phone Emulator requires missing Hyper-V & Pc missing Pre-requisties required Hyper-V

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am a beginner for windows phone app..I installed visual studio 2013 ultimate which includes windows phone 8 SDK.. (Blend for visual studio 2013)

I checked my Laptop windows 8 64 bit,core i3 Intel 1.8 GHz Processor..

When I started my first app then an error came in emulator..

"The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V. Your PC is missing the following pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V: Windows 8 Professional (64-bit)"

I have tried lot of times but icouldnot find any result..

I have searched Stack over flow but did not find any solution. Now I am asking to you people plz solve my problem.

I have checked systeminfo. and msinfo32   all having hyper-V.  SALT supporting,

this is also. http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-57-25-metablogapi/2480.011813_5F00_0935_5F00_HyperVonCli2.png

But in Turn Windows Features on and off,,does not contain folder Hyper-V.

Also Checked all these things,,my system is suppoting all these things. "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_enablehyperv"

Kindly help me about this problem...???

how can I become a member of the local Hyper-V Administrators group.?

Waiting........!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You need to be using a professional edition of windows 8. The home edition doesn't come with Hyper-V support.

Comment: @Petesh is saying right

Comment: Brother this is built In Addition. Windows Addition: windows 8 single lenguage. can I make it professional with extra features..?? or I have to install new window?

Comment: You can upgrade using [add features](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs). It costs $99 :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone Emulator requires missing Hyper-V](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236746/windows-phone-emulator-requires-missing-hyper-v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Windows 8 pro to make it work.